# PHP remove array of associative array that have a duplicate values of specific key

Tags: php, arrays

I've a array of associative array

```
array(xxx) {
 [0]=>
   array(3) {
    ["group_id"]=>2
    ["contact"]=> "foo"
    ["contact_email"]=> "foo@gmail.com"
   }
 [1]=>
   array(3) {
    ["group_id"]=>2
    ["contact"]=> "bar"
    ["contact_email"]=> "bar@gmail.com"
   }
  [2]=>
   array(3) {
    ["group_id"]=>2
    ["contact"]=> "foobar"
    ["contact_email"]=> "bar@gmail.com"
   }
 [3]=>
   array(3) {
    ["group_id"]=>2
    ["contact"]=> "bar"
    ["contact_email"]=> "bar@gmail.com"
   }
```

to remove duplicate arrays I do this

```
array_unique( $array, SORT_REGULAR );
```

But now I would like to do something more specific by eliminating only the arrays that have duplicated key value (contact_email) to obtain this result

```
 array(xxx) {
 [0]=>
   array(3) {
    ["group_id"]=>2
    ["contact"]=> "foo"
    ["contact_email"]=> "foo@gmail.com"
   }
 [1]=>
   array(3) {
    ["group_id"]=>2
    ["contact"]=> "bar"
    ["contact_email"]=> "bar@gmail.com"
   }
```

How could i do that? 
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extract to an array and index by `contact_email`.  Since there cannot be duplicate indexes you'll get the last occurrence:

```
$array = array_column($array, null, 'contact_email');
```

If you want to re-index that back to integers:

```
$array = array_values(array_column($array, null, 'contact_email'));
```

Comment: It is really great solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help

```
$arr = [['contact_email' => 'a@a.com'], ['contact_email' => 'a@a.com'], ['contact_email' => 'b@a.com']];
$result = [];
array_map(function ($item) use (&$result) {
    $result[$item['contact_email']] = $item;
}, $arr);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach` and group them by `contact_email`

```
$r = [];
foreach($a as $v){
 $r[$v['contact_email']] = $v;
}
print_r(array_values($r));// reorder index
```

Working example : https://3v4l.org/0oN8h